# Get specific page content using AJAX in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

So i've looked up and down for an answer and i couldn't find an answer to this but I've made it this far and i just need a little help to get over the hump.

So i am trying to get a specific page content from a div "#carslist" but when i make the ajax call it loads the entire page not just the content..I am fairly new to ajax and how it works..so any help will be amazing!

```
<div class="cars">
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://staging.idgadvertising.com/carshowcalendars/the-cars-list/',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
               jQuery(".cars").append(data);       
    },
    error: function(){ },
    complete: function(){ }
});



            });
            </script>

    </div>
```

I just need to get only the content that is in a div with ID #carslist but it shows the whole webpage. here is the screenshot below of my attempt

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdasM.jpg

Comment: I got this to work! thank you anyway who ever stumbles upon here. I decided to call a file instead of the page...seemed to work just fine!

Comment: " I decided to call a file instead of the page", can you answer your own question, possibly with a code example? Then it is complete :)

Comment: @Rustyjim its actually the same code as above but i called a php file instead of the web page URL. Do you wanna see that?

Comment: I said because I was reviewing and the question was not answered, your answer is helpful for others possibly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of calling a page i called a php file using ajax. i just had to be sure it was within the wordpress loop so that shortcodes worked. it worked, does the job and i can move on with my life!

```
<script>
            jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/wp-content/themes/carshowcalendar-child/carslist.php',
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(data){
               jQuery("select.ticket-meta").append(data);       
    },
    error: function(){ },
    complete: function(){ }
});
            });

</script>
```

and in that carslist.php file

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
require( '../../../wp-load.php' );
echo do_shortcode("[thecars]");

?>
```

and that shortcode i made like this

```
/****the cars shortcode*****/

function addcars() {

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 
$userID = $current_user->ID; 
$currentuser_ID = 'user_'.$userID; ?>


    <?php if( have_rows('my_cars', $currentuser_ID) ): ?>
         <?php while( have_rows('my_cars', $currentuser_ID) ): the_row(); ?>


        <option value="<?php echo the_sub_field('year'); ?> <?php echo the_sub_field('make'); ?> <?php echo the_sub_field('model'); ?> <?php echo the_sub_field('color'); ?>"><?php echo the_sub_field('year'); ?> <?php echo the_sub_field('make'); ?> <?php echo the_sub_field('model'); ?> <?php echo the_sub_field('year'); ?> <?php echo the_sub_field('color'); ?></option>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

<?php

}
add_shortcode( 'thecars', 'addcars' );
```